# How to get <th> in JSF datatable`

Tags: java, jsf

Please help me... I want my JSF datable to be rendered as follows i.e with employee name in  tag in every row.

```
<table>
<thead><tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Salary</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="employeeTableOddRow">
   <th>John</th>
   <td>2000.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th>Robert</th>     
   <td>3000.0</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But i am getting is as follows. The name is coming in  tag not in  tag. I have tried many combinations but couldn't get to it

```
<table>
<thead><tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Salary</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="employeeTableOddRow">
   <td>John</td>
   <td>2000.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Robert</td>
   <td>3000.0</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Code written is as follows

```
<h:dataTable value="#{userData.employees}" var="employee">
<h:column>                  
      <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>                 
      #{employee.name}
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">Salary</f:facet>
      #{employee.salary}
   </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

please let me know how to do this

Comment: `<f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>` renders `th` html tag, doesn't it ?

Comment: yes but that is making Name which is header row.. when I am puting <f:facet name="header">#{employee.name}</f:facet> it is rendering blank column

Comment: could you post an image how you would like the table to look like? `<th>` in `<tr>` does not make much sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h:dataTable value="#{userData.employees}" var="employee">
   <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">
          <h:outputText value="Name" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{employee.name}" />
   </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Example [here](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_dataTable.html)

Comment: yes but that is what it does for the first row with static data i.e Name and Salary but when I am puting <f:facet name="header">#{employee.name}</f:facet> it is rendering blank column

Comment: @Rachit M Garg. Updated my answer to make it more clear